# Draw shapes/text on canvas using layers or z-index

Tags: html, canvas

I draw several text elements using a for loop. 
But I want the first element to be drawn on top of all the other elments.
Other than reversing the loop, is there a way to define a layer number for a drawn element like text or shapes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the HTML5 Canvas—like SVG—uses a ["painters model"](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/render.html#PaintersModel) when rendering: the ink you lay down immediately dries on the canvas; successive draw calls go on top of the result.

Further, HTML5 Canvas—unlike SVG or HTML—uses a [*non-retained* (or immediate) graphics mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediate_mode): no objects are preserved corresponding to the original drawing commands after you have issued them.

Your options are:

- Change your loop, or otherwise implement your own layering system that queues up draw calls and then issues them in order from bottom to top.
- As @Stoive suggests, create separate (non-displayed) canvas elements programmatically, draw to them and then blit the results back to your main canvas in the order you like.
- Create multiple (displayed) canvases on the page and layer them using CSS, drawing to each as its own layer.

The last option allows you the most freedom, including the ability to dirty/clear just one of the layers at any time, or re-order the layers without having to recomposite them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of layers in `canvas` in the 2D context - think of it as a programmable paintbrush-like application.

You can, however, draw one canvas onto another using `context.drawImage` - so if you maintain each 'layer' in it's own canvas, and then compose them into the one for display, you could emulate the concept of layers.